# How to do this indices example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Beginner question, I have been trying to figure out how my book got the solution it did for this question :

$$\frac{(2r^2)^5 (3r^4)^3}{(6r^3)^2} = 24r^{16} $$

I get the $r^{16}$ part but how did they get 24?!

**EDIT**

Thanks to Brian for the clear answer below. In maths the same answer can be reached many ways, I tried like this :

$$\frac{2^5r^{10}   9r^{12}}{6r^6} = \frac{311r^{22}}{36r^6}= \text{something strange}$$

Please if you could let me know why my approach is leading to an incorrect answer and at which stage is my mistake?

Comment: If the $r^{16}$ worked for you, you could have replaced $2$ with $a$, $3$ with $b$, and $6$ with $ab$ and done the same calculations, then substituted back to calculate the result ($24$).

Comment: People do truly weird things with TeX on stackexchange.  Hint: There are manuals on the web.

Comment: @MichaelHardy kind of harsh no? its only my 2nd post, and I did read through the help, also your changes were not anything special.

Comment: I'm still getting used to the idea that some people never use TeX until they see it here.  Math classes should offer some TeX help so that students can write stuff in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{2^5\cdot3^3}{6^2}=\frac{2^2\cdot2^3\cdot3^2\cdot3}{6^2}=\frac{(2^2\cdot3^2)\cdot2^3\cdot3}{6^2}=\frac{(2\cdot3)^2\cdot8\cdot3}{6^2}=\frac{6^2\cdot24}{6^2}=24$$

**Added:** You tried

$$\frac{2^5r^{10} * 9r^{12}}{6r^6} = \frac{311r^{22}}{36r^6}= something-strange\;.$$

The first problem is that $(3r^4)^3=3^3r^{12}=27r^{12}$, not $9r^{12}$. I’m not sure how you got $311$: $2^5\cdot9=32\cdot9=288$, and the correct $2^5\cdot27=864$. In the denominator you have two errors that cancelled each other out: the original $(6r^3)^2$ is $6^2r^6$, not $6r^6$, but that means that $36r^6$ is correct. With the arithmetic errors corrected, you have a numerical coefficient of

$$\frac{864}{36}=24\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please if you could comment on my edit.

Comment: @Muhammad: I’ve added a comment on it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again I have learnt much from this!

Comment: @Muhammad: You’re welcome! Glad it helped.